# Trigger Click is not working with Gravity Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, triggers

I'm trying to fix not working download link, which have to also trigger Gravity Form submit.

Works only $("a")[0].click(); I added it to test overall code.

There are no errors in the console. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
  $('.download-pdf-link').click(function() {
         //  $('#gform_submit_button_3').trigger('click');
            
            $('#gform_submit_button_3').click();
            //$("a")[0].click();
        });

 <div class='gform_footer top_label'> <input type='submit' id='gform_submit_button_3' class='gform_button button' value='Submit' tabindex='52' onclick='if(window["gf_submitting_3"]){return false;}  window["gf_submitting_3"]=true;  ' onkeypress='if( event.keyCode == 13 ){ if(window["gf_submitting_3"]){return false;} window["gf_submitting_3"]=true;  jQuery("#gform_3").trigger("submit",[true]); }' /> 
     
<a class="btn download-pdf-link" download>Submit and Download</a>
```

p.s. Tested and not working:

```
 1. var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').click();

 2. $(this).closest("form").submit();
```

Comment: Where are you adding this code btw?  I use the snippet I suggested  for a lot of my forms so I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.download-pdf-link').click(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 0):

I found the working solution:

```
$('.download-pdf-link').click(function() {
    $("#gform_3").trigger("submit",[true]);
});
```